# How to update user role to i have the user three times with different user role

Tags: sql-server

I just want to make sure as I don't want to mess up anything as this is going right into production and I am not sure.

We have 3 roles for users 1, 2, 3 all users are by default role 1, However, I need to add to one user roles 2 and 3.

```
I am worried that if I use just UPDATE that it will just overwrite the default role. 

    UPDATE Users
    SET UserRole = 2 
    WHERE UserID = 26;
    
    would outcome of this be user role 1,2?
```

OR should i use insert?

Comment: No outcome would be 2, since 1 is replaced by 2. What is the datatype of UserRole ?

Comment: the type is int

Comment: If the type is int, It can only contain one numeric value, so 1 or 2 or N. If your users need more roles, you will probably need to change your model and add a many-to-many table UserRoles